# Android устройство не воспринимает ответ от сервера на POST запрос

Tags: android, php, post, запрос

Доброго времени суток! Прошу помочь! Имеется android устройство и php сервер. С устройства отправляется POST запрос на сервер, где в свою очередь исполняется sql запрос в Базу Данных и его результат отправляется через

```
echo($param);
```

а именно

```
if($n==5)
{

$query_dayend = "SELECT DayEnd FROM `Users` WHERE ID LIKE '$id'";
$res_dayend = mysql_query($query_dayend, $link);
$dayend_select = mysql_fetch_array($res_dayend);
$dayend = $dayend_select[0];
echo ($dayend);
}
```

Устройство принимает ответ от сервера таким образом

```
bTime = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
```

пробывал еще и так

```
bTime = convertStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
//.......
public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                try {
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                sb.append((line) + "\n");
                        }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                        try {
                                is.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
                return sb.toString();
        }
```

Но в результате программа получает пустую строчку, в ней ничего. На сервере все работает хорошо, так как если отсылать запрос через браузер (используя GET запрос в адресной строке) , то в ответ я получаю правильный ответ.
Также пробывал обработать ответ на сервере и передать просто цифру, но опять неудача((

```
if($n==5)
{
$query_dayend = "SELECT DayEnd FROM `Users` WHERE ID LIKE '$id'";
$res_dayend = mysql_query($query_dayend, $link);
$dayend_select = mysql_fetch_array($res_dayend);
$dayend = $dayend_select[0];
switch ($dayend) {
                case 21:
                        echo ("21");
                        break;
                case 9:
                        echo ("9");
                        break;
                // ...
                default:
                        break;

        }
}
```

Прошу сказать, что не так и что исправить в принятии ответа android устройством. (Я уверен ошибка в коде программы, а не на сервере)
P.S. если от сервера отправлять не результат на запрос,а просто цифру

```
if($n==5)
{
echo("9");
}
```

то все работает хорошо и устройство получает в ответ эту цифру 9. Почему так работает, а по другому нет(((
P.P.S. в базе хранится и передается как ответ числа от 0 до 23.

Comment: запрос работает правильно, это я проверил, так как кроме этого есть еще 4 они вносят изменения в базу. а этот 5ый запрос должен данные получать из базы, но первые 4 пашут а этот нет.

Comment: спасибо @Чад почему-то id в запрос не верный шел)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запишите со стороны сервера какой приходит запрос (чему равен $id) и приведите кусок кода который делает запрос, а не получает его. [[@bazanski](/users/7804/bazanski)](/users/7804/bazanski), думаю проблема у Вас в том, что вы не правильно передаёте/читаете айдюк, в следствии чего запрос из базы ничего не возвращает.

Ответ сервера, клиентское приложение получает, если скриптом просто написать его. 
Характер ответа из базы такой же как если просто скриптом. Итого у Вас два варианта - или что то ломается при получении из базы, или при запросе. САМ ОТВЕТ воспринимается на ура (Вы это проверили напечатав ответ сервером без запроса к базе).